# Drawing lines on PDF with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pypdf, pyfpdf

Is there a way to draw lines on a PDF file, by giving it coordinates of the start and end points? I have tried PyFPDF but cannot find much documentation about implementing it.

Comment: try `reportlab` with `canvas.line(378,723,580,723)` https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/03/08/a-simple-step-by-step-reportlab-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

The following code will draw a line in pdf:

```
pdf.set_draw_color(0, 0, 0) #black line
pdf.line(5, 16,205 ,16) #coordinate sequence: (x_start, y_start, x_end, y_end)
```